# Are Google Spreadsheet Add-ons counted as chrome apps or not?

Tags: google-sheets, google-chrome-app

Recently, i got email from chrome team, explaining, they will **remove support of chrome apps** till **june 2021**. they are suggesting to move on to another options like PWAs, Android Apps, etc. i searched about chrome apps, and got information that **it's built with HTML, CSS, JS, which can run everywhere, on any platform, and can access native hardware capabilities of device also**. i didn't develop anything like that.

But, i developed an **add-on for spreadsheet, and listed it on G Suite market place**. i just want to know, that **whether spreadsheet add-ons abre counted as chrome apps or not ?** if google removes support of chrome apps, it will effect my spreadsheet add-on or not ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: No, chrome apps are [completely different](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/first_app).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, chrome apps are a completely different thing [1].

[1] https://developer.chrome.com/apps/first_app